# How can my Eclipse RCP code list all installed features?

Tags: eclipse-rcp

I am writing a plugin for [Bioclipse](http://www.bioclipse.net), an Eclipse RCP application, and need some Java source code to list all installed features in a running Bioclipse instance. How can I programmatically list all installed features?

Answer (score 2):

You can try looking at `IBundleGroup,` `IBundleGroupProvider` and `Platform.getBundleGroupProviders`.  I believe this API is the source of the information you see in the about dialog.