# How can I programatically list all the features in a running Eclipse instance

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-rcp

I'm want to write a simple dependency visualisation plugin for Eclipse.  I've currently based it on the [Eclipse PDE Incubator Dependency Project](http://www.eclipse.org/pde/incubator/dependency-visualization/index.php).  However, I would like to group plugins into features to simplify the diagram.

I have started by using `Platform.getBundleGroupProviders` as answered by [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3104416/how-can-my-eclipse-rcp-code-list-all-installed-features).  However, this only lists features in the About section.  I'd like to get ALL the features.

How can I get the complete list of features?

Alternatively, are there any tools that already provide this functionality?

Comment: Which features do you think are missing?

Answer (score 0):

You could try `org.eclipse.update.configurator.ConfiguratorUtils.getCurrentPlatformConfiguration().getConfiguredFeatureEntries()`, but it returns exactly the same list of installed featured as `Platform.getBundleGroupProviders()[i].getBundleGroups()`

Sure you're missing some features ?