# Getting a list of installed features in an Eclipse RCP application

Tags: java, eclipse, osgi, eclipse-rcp

I'm trying to recreate a list of features that are installed (just as you can find in the installed software list of eclipse) through code.

I want to check in the code if certain features are present in the current state of my RCP Application.

I tried using the API coined here: [How can my Eclipse RCP code list all installed features?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3104416/how-can-my-eclipse-rcp-code-list-all-installed-features)

But I can't seem to recreate the list of all features. (only get around 9 features...)

This is the code I am using:

```
IBundleGroupProvider[] providers = Platform.getBundleGroupProviders();
IBundleGroup[] groups = providers[0].getBundleGroups();
```

Then when I iterate the groups I can't find my custom features...

Any thoughts?

Comment: Why do you do that? You should use dependencies or optional dependencies to other features and plugins in your own code, but explicitly listing installed features sounds like a crude workaround for another problem, on first sight.

Comment: Well actually I felt kinda dumb afterwards.. I just wanted a view to be able to check if an optional plug-in was installed... (to display additional info) but you totally don't have to list the installed features to be able to check that... but still if someone could tell me how to do this.. I would love to know how it is done :) that's why I don't close this topic

Comment: Please accept my asnser if it worked/helped you out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might work ?

```
for (IBundleGroupProvider provider : Platform.getBundleGroupProviders()) {
   for (IBundleGroup feature : provider.getBundleGroups()) {
      final String providerName = feature.getProviderName();
      final String featureId = feature.getIdentifier();
      for (Bundle bundle : feature.getBundles()) {
         ...
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The above code snippet does not list my bundles. However, the following test if bundle is present works:

```
Bundle plugin = Platform.getBundle("my.bundle.id");
if (plugin != null) {
    System.out.println("- bundle found: " + plugin.getSymbolicName());
}
```